# What is the purpose of spawn walker assignment?

Tags: jaseci

I've seen walkers being assigned to a variable as shown in the code below, however, the variable `this_test` is usable anywhere in the code since variable is assigned a python NONE type.

Is there is a purpose for this variable assignment or is there a way for the walker to return itself as an entity to the variable?

```
walker mytest {
    std.out("hello world");
}

walker init{
    root {
        this_test = spawn here walker::mytest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very well described in the docs but you can get `return` like behavior in a walker's run by specifying an `anchor` `has` variable. As per below.

```
walker demo {
  has anchor v = 75;
}

walker call {
  ret = spawn here walker::demo;
  std.out(ret);
}
```

In this example, the walker call will print `75` to the screen.